# Update query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database

Today I'm having a big problem with PHP. I'm trying to update a row on MySQL database. The biggest problem is because the query works if I insert directly in phpMyAdmin but not in my PHP script.

Follow my query (this is a value of $sqlQuery):

```
UPDATE my_table SET id = '64', title = 'test', another_column = 'asdasdasdasd 2', category = '1', author = '1', status = '0', column = '0', date_created = '2011-08-13 15:33:54' WHERE id = '64'
```

In my script, I created a loop to generate the code between "SET" and "WHERE" because it come from array.

Also, before you ask me If the connection are opened, I've checked with this code (below) and returned "opened":

```
if (!$conn->connection) echo "closed";
else echo "opened";
```

My script to run the query:

```
if (mysql_query($sqlQuery, $conn->connection)) {
    $sqlResult = array(
        "status" => "ok",
        "result" => "edited"
    );
} else {
    $sqlResult = array(
        "status" => "error",
        "result" => "$sqlQuery"
    );
}
```

It always return the "else" array (status = error and result = $sqlQuery).

Comment: Considered [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) for details?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried running your query directly against your MySQL database (either command-line or in MySQL Workbench)?

Answer (score 3):

You should `echo mysql_error();` to output the error message before trying to debug, but your error is probably cause by `column = '0'` since `column` is a reserved word in MySQL you *must* surround it with backticks like `` `column` = '0' ``

Comment: I have changed a few name of columns. "my_table", "another_column" and "column" are not the real name (but I think the real names are not reserved too).

Comment: @Lucas Okay, good to know. Could you show us the output of `mysql_error()`?

Comment: The MAMP are setting by default to hide the errors. I wasn't knew that!
Sorry guys!

The error appear (after I use this tutorial: http://www.jhuskisson.com/code-tidbits/re-enabling-error-reporting-in-mamp) and I fix the error.

The problem was because the connection are closed. I closed the previous and opened a new and executed my query. It works well!

Thanks a lot to all!

Comment: @Lucas You should post that as an answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you setting `id = '64' WHERE id = '64'`? Id's are `INT` anyway, you should not be quoting them.

Also, change `"result" => "$sqlQuery"` to `"result" => $sqlQuery` and do a `var_dump($sqlQuery)` to assist with debugging.

Comment: I tryed do what you say before (I run a loop to check if is_numeric and remove the quotes).

Comment: The MAMP are setting by default to hide the errors. I wasn't knew that!
Sorry guys!

The error appear (after I use this tutorial: http://www.jhuskisson.com/code-tidbits/re-enabling-error-reporting-in-mamp) and I fix the error.

The problem was because the connection are closed. I closed the previous and opened a new and executed my query. It works well!

Thanks a lot to all!

Answer (score 1):

Is your `id` field an auto-incrementing primary key? If so, then you will not be able to set it in your query (you shouldn't be anyway, since it's part of your `WHERE` clause). In general, you should only update the fields that are actually being changed (and primary key values typically should not change as part of an update).

Comment: The MAMP are setting by default to hide the errors. I wasn't knew that!
Sorry guys!

The error appear (after I use this tutorial: http://www.jhuskisson.com/code-tidbits/re-enabling-error-reporting-in-mamp) and I fix the error.

The problem was because the connection are closed. I closed the previous and opened a new and executed my query. It works well!

Thanks a lot to all!